# MySQL: Get count for each range

Tags: mysql, sql

There is mysql  Ver 8.0.18 value_table as:

```
value count
1    3
11   1
12   2
22   5
31   1
34   3
35   1
40   3
46   7
```

What is query to get a total count for each dozen (1-10 - first dozen,11-20 - second , etc..)
as:

```
1   3
2   3
3   5
4   8
5   7
```

Query should be flexible, so when some records added to value_table , for example

```
51 2
62 3
```

so, it is not necessary to change a query by adding new range (51-60 - 6-th dozen, etc.)

Comment: You're aware that a 'dozen' is twelve?

Comment: google translator  recommended me a "dozen" . English it is not my native . Btw , what is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want division and aggregation:

```
select min(value), sum(count)
from t
group by floor(value / 10);
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if the first column should be `min(value)` or `floor(value / 10) + 1`.